Scrape data from FDA Recall using python
http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfres/res.cfm?id=207968
Also I want to know , am i able to use api to get all the information from the link?
Please suggest any possible way I tried to get the device classification data with the recall.

You can use the following openFDA pipeline's source code as a reference for your work: https://github.com/FDA/openfda/blob/master/openfda/device_recall/pipeline.py
